# drupal page innerlink doesn't navigate to the div

Tags: html, drupal, drupal-6, cck

I have problem with navigation to the div of a page with normal html hash link. which redirects to another page with div id. here is the page where the link exists.

http://tayc.com/junior-sailing

There are links for Introduction to Sailing, private lesson etc. but when i click on the link it should navigate to the div of that page for introduction to sailing , private lesson and so on.. but it is not working.

can any one help me with this.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen that when i click on the "Introduction to Sailing" link it is moving to the corresponding content using jquery or javascript.(May be this will be problem.So try to remove that jquery or javascript functionality and check again)

If you want to achieve by url navigation.look into following code.

```
<a href="#link_intro">Introduction to Sailing</a>

On the content part:use link(Dont miss the href="#")
<a id="link_intro" href="#">Introduction to Sailing</a> as HEADING to the contents.
```